# Finding match and getting the data from same row

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with this code to find a match between `A column value(sheet1)` and `E column value (sheet2)`. If there is a match then get the value from that row and put that value in `sheet2`. The code works great and faster. However, I am facing this weird problem, despite having a match in (especially data in the middle of the column) between `A column value(sheet1)` and `E column value (sheet2)` it's not getting me anything.

```
Dim wsDest1 As Worksheet
Set wsDest1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")

Dim wsLookup1 As Worksheet
Set wsLookup1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

Dim lasRow1 As Long
lasRow1 = wsDest1.Cells(wsDest1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Dim MatchedRow1 As Double

Dim iRow1 As Long
For iRow1 = 2 To lasRow1
    MatchedRow1 = 0 'initialize!
    On Error Resume Next
    MatchedRow1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(wsDest1.Cells(iRow1, "E").Value, wsLookup1.Columns("A"), 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If MatchedRow1 <> 0 Then
        If wsDest1.Cells(iRow1, "E").Value = wsLookup1.Cells(MatchedRow1, "A").Value Then
            wsDest1.Cells(iRow1, "A").Value = wsLookup1.Cells(MatchedRow1, "J").Value
            wsDest1.Cells(iRow1, "B").Value = wsLookup1.Cells(MatchedRow1, "H").Value
            wsDest1.Cells(iRow1, "C").Value = wsLookup1.Cells(MatchedRow1, "G").Value
            wsDest1.Cells(iRow1, "D").Value = wsLookup1.Cells(MatchedRow1, "N").Value
            wsDest1.Cells(iRow1, "F").Value = wsLookup1.Cells(MatchedRow1, "D").Value
        End If
    End If
Next iRow1
```

Comment: There is nothing weird about it, it's exactly how you have programmed it `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(wsDest1.Cells(iRow1, "E").Value, wsLookup1.Columns("A"), 1)` - the `1` at the end is the equivalent of `TRUE` for "Approximate match".  Change it to `0` ('FALSE`) and you will get exact match.

Comment: thank you brother it worked. i have one more similar code with different logic and facing the same problem. wish you could review that code